# vb.net form is visible before Load event is done when using Mac remote desktop

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, macos

i have a scenario involving 2 forms `frmSplash` and `frmmain` whereby :-
(a)I need to load and show `frmSplash`
(b)load `frmmain`, BUT dont show it until some computation that happen in the `Load()` event is complete at which point I hide `frmSplash`. That is how it should work anyway.

Both `frmSplash` and `frmmain` are loaded in a sub Main as below:

```
sub main
{
frmSplash .show()

 Application.Run(New frmMain)
}
```

PROBLEM is that when we get to running `frmMain`,  its form shows up BEFORE the `load()` event is done WHEN running the application via remote desktop connection from a Mac client. There is no problem with remoting from windows machines as the `frmMain` does NOT appear until its load is executed and `frmSplash` has been hidden by `frmmain`.

Comment: I'm away from my pc at the moment, but is is possible to set the frmMain visible property in design mode to false and then programmatically set it to visible after the computation has finished?